# How do I set the component background to a specific color in JGraphX?

Tags: java, swing, background, jcomponent, jgraphx

I want to make the background of a JGraphX graph component (https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx) a specific color all over. I tried the standard call for any Swing component:

```
graphComponent.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

but this has no effect. I tried forcing a repaint of the component also, no luck. Is the call incorrect, or is there some specific way to force a refresh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `mxGraphComponent` extends `JScrollPane` change the background of the view port:

```
graphComponent.getViewport().setOpaque(true);
graphComponent.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

From [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) docs:

> This can be accomplished by setting the background
>   color of the viewport, via scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground().
>   The reason for setting the color of the viewport and not the
>   scrollpane is that by default JViewport is opaque which, among other
>   things, means it will completely fill in its background using its
>   background color. Therefore when JScrollPane draws its background the
>   viewport will usually draw over it.